# Django template not including a static css file?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a simple django app and I'm trying to load a static css file, but it doesn't appear to be working. I can navigate to the css file in my browser.

Here's the beginning of my template file:

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'datasets/css/styles.css' %}">

{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="mb-4">Datasets</h1>
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for dataset in datasets %}
              <tr>
                <td>
```

And here is my settings.py:

```
"""
from pathlib import Path
from environs import Env

env = Env()
env.read_env()

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",  # new
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    # Third-party
    "crispy_forms",
    "crispy_bootstrap5",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "debug_toolbar",
    # Local
    "accounts.apps.AccountsConfig",
    "pages.apps.PagesConfig",
    "books.apps.BooksConfig",
    'datasets'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",  # new
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "django_project.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "django_project.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
   "default": env.dj_db_url("DATABASE_URL", default="postgres://postgres:postgres@db/postgres")
}

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]
print(f'Static files dirs: {STATICFILES_DIRS}')
#STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / ]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
#STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
```

And here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import DatasetListView, DatasetDetailView
#from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views
import uuid


urlpatterns = [
    path('browse/', DatasetListView.as_view(), name='dataset_browse'),
    path('datasets/<uuid:pk>/', DatasetDetailView.as_view(), name='dataset_detail'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

#urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Here is my (relevant) directory structure:

```
.
├── datasets
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls copy working1a.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views copy working1a.py
│   └── views.py
├── django_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── covers
│   │   ├── dfp.jpg
│   │   ├── dfp_I4SCkr4.jpg
│   │   ├── dfp_KUn7MFY.jpg
│   │   └── dfp_MYQvv1k.jpg
│   ├── css
│   │   └── base.css
│   ├── datasets
│   │   └── css
│   │       └── styles.css
│   ├── images
│   │   └── dfp.jpg
│   └── js
│       └── base.js
```

What am I doing wrong?!?

I am trying to vertically center the contents of the , and when I inspect the page, I can see the base.css, but I don't see a reference to the styles.css file and the contents are not centered.

I've tried setting the static dir using os join like: STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static') ]

Edit to add _base.html:

```
    {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{% block title %}Bookstore{% endblock title %}</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Bookstore</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'book_list' %}">Books</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
          </li>
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">Log Out</a>
          </li>
          {% else %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Log In</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" >
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="{% static 'js/base.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess it's about template inheritance. Show your _base.html

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I edited my original post to include the _base.html. I don't know much about template inheritance so I need to read about it and see if that helps me figure anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Error reason

Template inheritance can *override* only blocks defined in ancestor. It cannot add brand new blocks - template engine has no idea where in the final page it is supposed to appear.

You have this block:

```
  <div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
  </div>
```

and Django knows where to put `block content` code from inherited templates - inside this div.

This `link`

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'datasets/css/styles.css' %}">
```

from the inherited template is not located in any defined *block* and even if you write something like

```
{% block styles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'datasets/css/styles.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

Django would still have no idea where this block is supposed to be located - it is not mapped to any place in `_base.html`. *Somewhere above block "content"* - no, it does not work.

## Solution

To fix this define additional block in the `_base.html` so inherited templates can override it:

_base.html

```
<head>
  ...
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
  {% block styles %}
  {% endblock %}
</head>
...
  <div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
  </div>
...
```

any inherited template

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% block styles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'datasets/css/styles.css' %}">
{% endblock styles %}

{% block content %}
<p>My content</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: That makes sense and it works now. Thanks for the thorough explanation.